# Tooltip of the content from database wisth css

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tooltip

I have a container with Image and text from the database. when hovering on Container I need a tooltip from the database to be displayed

ASP.net

```html
 <div class="Imagecontainer" style="float:left; width:100px; text-align:center;">
   <asp:Image ID="InvestorImg" runat="server" src="images\Invs.png"  />
      <br /><br />
      <span style=" font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold; color: black;">Investors</span>
      <br /><br />
       <asp:Label ID="NewAccountsLabel" runat="server"  CssClass="NewAccountsLabel_style" ></asp:Label>      
 </div>
```

I page load I'm calling another method to load data into NewAccountsLabel

```
 private void NewAccounts()
    {
        siteSoapClient site = new siteSoapClient();
        DataSet NewAccountsds1 = site.GetNewAccounts();
        NewAccountsLabel.Text = "New" + "<br/>" + "Accounts :" + NewAccountsds1.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();

}
```

In the query, I have a date field which I want to display as a tooltip with CSS. I knew how to add a tooltip without CSS but I don't know how to add CSS to it

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.Imagecontainer').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.tooltip').html('<img src="' + 'Put Your Value`enter code here` + '" alt="loading...">').fadeIn();
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('.tooltip').hide();
    }).append('<span class="tooltip"></span>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add id for div tag

`<div class="Imagecontainer" id="DivID" runat="server" style="float:left; width:100px; text-align:center;">
   <asp:Image ID="InvestorImg" runat="server" src="images\Invs.png"  />
      <br /><br />
      <span style=" font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold; color: black;">Investors</span>
      <br /><br />
       <asp:Label ID="NewAccountsLabel" runat="server"  CssClass="NewAccountsLabel_style" ></asp:Label>

 </div>`

Then in backend code, Use DivID.Attributes.Add("title", "Your Text From Database");

```
private void NewAccounts()
{
    siteSoapClient site = new siteSoapClient();
    DataSet NewAccountsds1 = site.GetNewAccounts();
    NewAccountsLabel.Text = "New" + "<br/>" + "Accounts :" + 
        NewAccountsds1.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
DivID.Attributes.Add("title", "Your Text From Database");

}
```